# global variables in a loaded page

Tags: php, jquery

I have my index page which uses a script to load another page into a div

```
  $('#TransportPlanning').click(function() { 
      mainpage = $('#FloatMain')

      mainpage.load('create_diary.php') 

  });
```

The page loads ok into my div, but I want to share php variables from one page to another, I thought the newly loaded page would be able to reference the main index variables but this is not the case , I have tried global but still not working

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Share Variable Between Two Different PHP Scripts, Make It Super Global :

Use

```
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['key']=value;
```

In index.php And read it in crate_diary.php as :

```
session_start();
$key=$_SESSION['key'];
```

And Do That ($key) Variable Specific code in create_diary.php.

Using Session or Cookies Prevent Unethical Use of Your Sensitive Data. You Can Also Use Cookies Instead Of Session. But Dont forget to unset session after you've done with it. Specially When you are dealing with cookies because Session will get automatically destroyed when user closes browser but this isn't true with cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are not shared across scripts.

Pass them as query arguments instead, like:

```
mainpage.load('create_diary.php?key=value');
```

The value will be available within your `create_diary` script in `$_GET['key']`