# Accessing variable inside function - php

Tags: php

i need to access a variable which is declared in another php file within a function.. How can i do it?

a.php

```
<?php

$global['words']=array("one","two","three");

echo "welcome"
?>
```

b.php

```
<?php

$words = $global['words'];
require_once('a.php');

print_r($global['words']);

function fun()
{

print_r($global['words']); // not displaying here

}

fun();
?>
```

now i am able to access the "$global['words']" variable in b.php file, but not within function, how can i make it visible inside the function?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913718/global-variables-in-a-loaded-page/14913814#14913814)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred option is to pass as a parameter:

```
function fun($local) {
    print_r($local['words']);
}

fun($global);
```

If for some reason you can't use that approach, then you can declare the variable as global:

```
function fun() {
    global $global;
    print_r($global['words']);
}

fun();
```

Or use the `$GLOBALS` array:

```
function fun() {
    print_r($GLOBALS['global']['words']);
}

fun();
```

But in general, using global variables is [considered bad practise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715897/why-is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-global-reference-inside-functions).

Comment: How is this different than my answer?

Comment: Because I've recommended using a parameter, which is the correct way to do it (whether the OP asked for it or not).

Comment: still, how is it different?

Answer (score 0):

actually your function does n't know about anything outside it, if it's not a classes, or global php vars such as `$_POST` ,  you can try to define function as:

```
function fun() use ($globals)
{

}
```

Comment: The `use` keyword is only available on anonymous functions.

Comment: thanks i forgot about it (